# VBA userform entry saves on wrong worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem regarding the location where my data entries get saved.

I have the code below for a button to add some entry on the worksheet "PL2_steel". The problem is that when the form loads, if instead of sheet "PL2_steel" another sheet is activated at that moment, it just saves the entry on the active sheet (and not on "PL2_steel").

```
Private Sub but_spl2addelement_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL2_steel")
    
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("PL2_steel").ListObjects("Tbl_spl2elements").DataBodyRange

    
            '''''''''''''''Validation'''''''''
            
    If txt_SPL2code.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please assign a unique identifier code!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With sh
        Cells(lr + 1, "A").value = Me.txt_SPL2code.value
        Cells(lr + 1, "B").value = Me.Combo_spl2elements.value
        Cells(lr + 1, "C").value = Me.txt_spl2gwp.value
        Cells(lr + 1, "D").value = Me.Txt_spl2count.value
        Cells(lr + 1, "E").value = Val(Me.Txt_spl2count.value) * Val(Me.txt_spl2gwp.value)
        Cells(lr + 1, "R").value = Val(Me.Txt_spl2count.value) * Val(Me.txt_spl2gwp.value)
    End With

        Me.Combo_spl2elements = ""
        Me.txt_spl2gwp.value = ""
        Me.Txt_spl2count.value = ""
       End Sub
```

I suppose I have declared the sheet properly. What could be the problem then?

Comment: With sh End With insert a dot before all Cells references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `Cells()` is handled as `ActiveWorkbook.Cells()` - To reference the Cells of a certain Worksheet you use `ws.Cells()` (In general the way you access properties or methods of an object is `object.property` or `object.method`

This also is true in `With` blocks. All the with does is: save you from having to type out the object you are referring to over and over again. So if you for example have the following code:

```
obj.property
obj.property
obj.property
```

you can use a with statement to avoid having to explicitly name obj every single time. - So you just wrap the statements into a with block and then remove `obj` from each line. You are then left with:

```
With obj
  .property
  .property
  .property
End With
```

The `.` signifies that this is the property/method of an object. If you didn't use the dot it would just be a normal variable.

For example see:

```
Dim name As String
name = "Julian"

With obj
  .name = name
  name = .surname
End With

Debug.Print obj.name 'Output: "Julian"
Debug.Print name 'Output: "" // provided obj.surname was not previously set to a value
```

For documentation on the With statement see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement

Comment: Many thanks for your thorough explanation. It does work properly now